# Just can't seem to get mysql query correct

Tags: mysql

I am trying to get results that i know are there but just can't seem to get the query right. I am using the following:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    carpets AS c 
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r ON c.id = r.carpet_id 
WHERE 
    c.active = '1' 
    AND **((r.relation_type = '5') 
    AND (r.related_id = '1' ))** 
    *AND* ((r.relation_type = '4') 
    AND (r.related_id = '1')) 
    AND (c.width_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '17') 
    AND (c.width_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
    AND (c.height_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '29') 
    AND (c.height_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
ORDER BY 
    c.item_no
```

as you can see i am trying get results that have two matching fields in a second table if i change the and that is in italics to an or i get results but it is results for both i need the results that are in the set prior to the and which is bold

so it would be something like:

list that has relation type 5 and 4

keep in mind that related id could be different for both there are three colums carpet_id,related_id,relation_type

thanks for any help

c_categories
Column  Type    Null    Default     Comments
id  int(11)     No
title   varchar(250)    No
active  int(11)     No
weight  int(11)     No
template_id     int(11)     No

c_sizes
Column  Type    Null    Default     Comments
id  int(11)     No
title   varchar(250)    No
active  int(11)     No
weight  int(11)     No
template_id     int(11)     No

carpet_relations

Column  Type    Null    Default     Comments

carpet_id   int(11)     No      <------ signifies which carpet the relationship is with

related_id  int(11)     No      <------ the id of the c_size or c_categories to use

relation_type   int(11)     No  <------ signifies which table either c_sizes or c_categories

Comment: Do you mean type 5 OR 4?

Comment: just to make sure it is understood    5 would be stating the relationship is for a category and the 1 that is with it states it is category 1          and then the 4 would be stating the relationship is for a template and the 1 that is with it states it is template 1..........i didn't write or design the database but i have to deal with it

Comment: it is to narrow a search so it would need to be both they select category 1 as the main and then narrow it down with category 2 and if i do or then it brings more results rather than less results like it should

Comment: can you printscreent he database schema or copy the data dictionary from phpmyadmin?

Comment: do you think that it can't be done? if not i was just thinking i could do one query for the results with 5 and put in an array and then do a second query for the 4....not the cleanest i would prefer to keep it all in one query

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Now I think I understand your problem - you're after the intersection of results of type 5 and type 4.

This could be done in PHP as you mention by doing two queries and intersecting them, or you can do this in MySQL by joining the `carpet_relations` table on twice like so:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    carpets AS c 
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r1 ON c.id = r1.carpet_id 
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r2 ON c.id = r2.carpet_id
WHERE 
    c.active = '1' 
    AND (r1.relation_type = '5')
    AND (r1.related_id = '1' )
    AND (r2.relation_type = '4')
    AND (r2.related_id = '1')
    AND (c.width_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '17') 
    AND (c.width_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
    AND (c.height_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '29') 
    AND (c.height_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
ORDER BY 
    c.item_no
```

Comment: perfect that did the trick.....thank you sooooo much now i just need to look it over and understand what you are doing as joins and queries this complex is new too me i usually do simpler ones without joins but this works great!

Comment: Glad it works for you. Basically you have to join the carpet_relations table on twice, once to get carpets where the relation_type is 5, and another time when the relation_type is 4. If you wanted to add another constraint, like relation_type is 7, you'd have to join the carpet_relations table on again. Good luck.

Comment: Oh and please click accept if you think this is the correct answer ;)

Answer (score 2):

Change this:

`((r.relation_type = '5') AND (r.related_id = '1' )) AND ((r.relation_type = '4') AND (r.related_id = '1'))`

to this:

`(r.relation_type = '5' OR r.relation_type = '4') AND (r.related_id = '1')`

Comment: it needs to be (5 and 1) and (4 and 1)

Comment: As @UgurGumushan pointed out, `r.relation_type` cannot be 4 *and* 5 at the same time.

Answer (score 1):

For flexibility's sake:

```
r.relation_type IN (4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
AND ((r.relation_type = '5')
AND ((r.relation_type = '4')
```

you are expecting relation type to be 5 and 4 at the same time.

Would you like to have some "or" in your salad?

edit:

```
SELECT 
    * 
FROM 
    carpets AS c 
    INNER JOIN carpet_relations AS r ON c.id = r.carpet_id 
WHERE 
    c.active = '1' 
    AND 
((r.relation_type = '5') AND (r.related_id = '1' ))
    OR 
((r.relation_type = '4') AND (r.related_id = '1')) 

    AND (c.width_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '17') 
    AND (c.width_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
    AND (c.height_feet BETWEEN '0' AND '29') 
    AND (c.height_inches BETWEEN '0' AND '11') 
ORDER BY 
    c.item_no
```

solves your problem.

Comment: with the table the 5 would represent category relation with the relation id equals the category id        and then the 4 represents the template relationship with the relation id is the template id that is why i need both

Comment: i tried that then it brings up 168 things so it would be that when a user does a search say for long rugs so that is the overall category then they click that they want to narrow it down to oriental rugs i don't want a full list of both long rugs and oriental just the oriental rugs that are also a long rug